# Adding new ListView conflict with Linearlayout

Tags: android

After adding a `ListView` in the layout, the `ListView` was able to work but upon clicking on the `RelativeLayout` above the `ListView`, a white screen appears and the whole app crashes and restarts.

Here is the newly added `ListView`:

```
ListView simpleList;
String numberList[] = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"};

simpleList = (ListView) entryLayout.findViewById(R.id.simpleListView);
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(activity, R.layout.string_layout, R.id.label, numberList);
simpleList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

How can I resolve this?

The stacktrace is this:

```
requestLayout() improperly called by com.nightonke.boommenu.BMBShadow{d123f7 V.E...... ......ID 0,0-168,186 #7f100186 app:id/shadow} during layout: running second layout pass.  

Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView .   

E/HAL: Dawei load: module=/system/lib64/hw/gralloc.msm8953.so
```

The top 2 lines are in the declaration part of the Java class and the last 3 lines are in the constructor part.

The xml layouts:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/keysLayout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/topLeft_guideline"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/topRight_guideline"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/secondLevel_guideline"
  app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/thirdLevel_guideline">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/keys"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/childMain"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/topLeft_guideline"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/topRight_guideline"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/keysLayout">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/childLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_gradient_child_keys"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="none">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/child"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:paddingEnd="8dp"
            android:paddingStart="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp" />

        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/childtwo"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/topLeft_guideline"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/topRight_guideline"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/bottom_guideline"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/childMain">


    <ListView 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/simpleListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:divider="#f00"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/bottom_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.504"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/topLeft_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/topRight_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/childMain">

    </ListView>


    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Post the stacktrace from the crash and a little more context as to where this code is, please.

Comment: Not able to find any ListView in xml, please make question more clear with corresponding and relevant codes so that someone can help you out.

Comment: Hi @codeMagic, I have edited the stacktrace from crash and context, appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi @SachinVarma I have put in the ListView in xml, sorry for the mix up. Thanks for looking into it